# Make recent posts float left using one div for each post

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress static site where I want to display some recent posts.
I'm able to display the recent posts, but I want each recent post to be inside of a div on it's own. This is the code I'm currently using:

```
<div id="senastebox">
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) ); ?></a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More...</a>
<?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

How do I assign a div to each and one of the displayed recent posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like adding a new `div` at each `while:endwhile` itteration?

```
<div id="senastebox">
<?php 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); 
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : 
        $the_query -> the_post(); 
?>
<div class="floating-post">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) ); ?></a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More...</a>
</div>
<?php 
    endwhile;
?>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.floating-post { float: left }
```